# Handling multiple messages in akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Which is the best approach for handling multiple messages in an actor model?

If for example you need 2 distinct message returns from an actor, how is it possible to access and retreive both messages from another actor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actor in Akka can respond to many different kinds of messages, and send any messages as well...

```
case class Message1(id: Long)
case class Message2(thing: String)
case class Response1(x: Int)
case class Response2(y: Int)

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    def receive = { 
         case Message1(id) => sender ! Response1(id)
         case Message2(t)  => sender ! Response2(1)
    }
}
```

All you have to do is look for them with case statements in a `receive` method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that show how to handle different results from an actor.

Given the following actor:

```scala
case object GiveMeAFruit

trait Fruit

case class Apple(size: Int) extends Fruit

case class Pear(color: String) extends Fruit

class FruitNinja extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case GiveMeAFruit =>
      if (math.random > 0.5)
        sender ! Apple(42)
      else
        sender ! Pear("yellow")
  }
}
```

**Communicating from another actors**

```scala
class HungryActor extends Actor {
  val fruitNinja = context.actorOf(Props[FruitNinja])

  override def preStart = {
    context.system.scheduler.schedule(5 seconds, 5 seconds, fruitNinja, GiveMeAFruit)
  }

  def receive = {
    // handle different returns from FruitNinja
    case Apple(size) =>
      println(s"Got an apple sized $size.")
    case Pear(color) =>
      println(s"Got a $color pear")
  }
}
```

**Communicating with the actor from 'normal' code**

```scala
import akka.pattern.ask

def eatSomething = {
  // create an instance of the actor using an actorsystem in scope
  val fruitNinja = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[FruitNinja])

  (fruitNinja ? GiveMeAFruit).mapTo[Fruit].map{
    // handle different returns from FruitNinja
    case Apple(size) =>
      println(s"Got an apple sized $size.")
    case Pear(color) =>
      println(s"Got a $color pear")
  }
}
```